パソコンのフォルダの権限とLaravelについて！
Laravel10のbreezeを落として来ようとしたらエラーが発生しました。AIに聞いたらパーミションの問題とせつめいされましたがLaravel10１の一番上のフォルダには書き込み、読み込み権限もチェックがついていました。どうしていいかわからないので教えて頂けますか？
環境はWindows 10でXAMPPを使っています。よろしくお願いします。
composer require laravel/breeze --dev

In RequireCommand.php line 160:

  file_get_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\php\Lesson): Failed to open stream: Permission denied


require [--dev] [--dry-run] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--fixed] [--no-suggest] [--no-progress] [--no-update] [--no-install] [--no-audit] [--audit-format AUDIT-FORMAT] [--update-no-dev] [-w|--update-with-dependencies] [-W|--update-with-all-dependencies] [--with-dependencies] [--with-all-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [-m|--minimal-changes] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--apcu-autoloader-prefix APCU-AUTOLOADER-PREFIX] [--] [<packages>...]


C:\xampp\htdocs\php\Lesson
ディレクトリにアクセス権限が無いと言っていませんか？
Lessonの権限を再度確認してみてください
